# VBA For Each not going to each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with this part of my code. It's supposed to go to each worksheet that has a name starting with `Employee-` but it's only going to the first sheet named `Employee-Lilly` and looping the filter over and over.

I need to code to go to all the sheets which names start with `Employee-` and filter.

```
 For Each sheetObject In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If sheetObject.name Like "Employee*" Then
        Set target = sheetObject.Range("A1:O80000")

        Selection.AutoFilter
        target.AutoFilter _
            Field:=13, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & Date
    End If
Next sheetObject
```

Comment: You'll probably need to change `Selection.Autofilter` to `Target.Autofilter` since you never actually do a `Target.Select` (nor should you since it's totally unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Avoid using **Selection** will speed up your code.

```
For Each sheetObject In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 If sheetObject.name Like "Employee*" Then
    with sheetObject.Range("A1:O80000")
       .AutoFilter _
        Field:=13, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & Date
    end with
  End If
Next sheetObject
```